# What's a « 1-Ratio» ? From a text on Capital's share of GDP

Tags: economic-growth, growth-accounting

[In this article](http://evonomics.com/capitals-share-of-income-is-way-higher-than-you-think/), the writer talks about the «capital share, as a percent of GDP — here just 1 – labor share percentage»

What's this 1-labour share percentage?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm pretty sure he means "1 minus the labour share percentage", i.e. he's estimating the capital share of GDP as the proportion of GDP not going to labour.  It's not typeset well, but he has used an em-dash (longer) after "GDP" and a minus sign (shorter) after "1".